# C# - Program is slowing down very quickly, why?

Tags: c#, performance, console

I have made a very simple brute-force password cracking program (it's terrible, I know), and I have a thread running which outputs how many combinations per second, and how many combinations total it has tried.

It starts off for a split second doing 2000 combinations per second, and then very swiftly drops to around 150, then slowly decreases all the way down to 1 after an hour or so.

This is the thread I run:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateGuessCount));
thread.Start();
tring currentGuess = "a";
while (currentGuess != password)
{
    currentGuess = Shift(currentGuess);
    guesses++;
    guessesPerSecond++;
}

static void UpdateGuessCount()
{
    while (true)
    {
        mre.WaitOne();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Current guesses: " + guesses);
        Console.WriteLine("Current guesses per second: " + guessesPerSecond);
        guessesPerSecond = 0;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The 'Shift' method changes the combination, shifts it upwards. For example, Shift("a") would become "b" and so on.

Why does this happen, and is there anything I can do to stop it happening / make it faster?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Shift source code:

```
static string Shift(string toShift)
{
    char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    char[] shiftChars = new char[toShift.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(toShift.ToCharArray(), shiftChars, toShift.Length);
    shiftChars[shiftChars.Length - 1] = ' ';
    int index = 0;
    char chr = shiftChars[index];

    if (chr == '0')
    {
        while (chr == '0')
        {
            shiftChars[index] = 'a';
            index++;
            chr = shiftChars[index];
        }
        if (shiftChars[index] != ' ')
        {
            int charIndex = 0;
            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                if (c == chr)
                {
                    shiftChars[index] = chars[charIndex + 1];
                }
                charIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            shiftChars[index] = 'a';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        int charIndex = 0;
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            if (c == chr)
            {
                shiftChars[index] = chars[charIndex + 1];
            }
            charIndex++;
        }
    }

    string returnString = "";
    foreach (char c in shiftChars)
    {
        returnString = returnString + c;
    }

    return returnString;
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to say. I'd say you should profile it. Perhaps `Shift` is implemented in such a way that it gets slower depending on how big the string is.

Comment: 1) You have synchronization issues with the current code. 2) Please post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

Comment: More code would help in this case I think. Could you put in the shift code ?

Comment: I also think there are synchronization issues. The only way to know is to view the source for the Shift() method.

Comment: Is the size of the combinations growing as time passes? Are the guessed passwords growing in length? The more data it needs to process, the slower it will get.

Comment: EDIT: Added 'Shift' code. Yeah it does get longer, and I know that increases time taken, but I didn't expect it to increase it that much.

Comment: `returnString = returnString + c;` is going to be horrible on your garbage collector. You really should be using a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use a StringBuilder and see if it makes a difference. EDIT: Made a huge difference! Was at 29,000 per second for a split second, then decreased from 2500 to 600 in about 1 minute.

Comment: For me what made a difference is removing the foreach loop and just doing  return new string(shiftChars); But I think there is a lot of stuff that could be optimized in the shift method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on optimising it now I know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program maintains your original algorithm and runs at ~20M compares/sec on my laptop and will not degrade over time.  I was getting the same ~2k/sec with the original and had the quick degradation.

The core issue with your implementation was excessive string allocation which lead to a lot of GC activity. The primary culprit was the following line in the Shift()  method:

```
char[] shiftChars = new char[toShift.Length + 1];
```

It was incrementing the length of your guess string on each call to Shift(). After 20k compares you had a 20k long guess string, with only the first couple characters being used.

Shift() was also taking a string as a parameter and returning as string as well. That means allocations on each call to shift.  You were already using char[] to do the work so just accept and return those.  This way we pre-allocate the guess buffer and just move around the characters inside.

```
static string Shift(string toShift);
```

Replaced with:

```
static void Shift(ref char[] shiftChars, ref int tailIndex)
```

There were a couple spots where you were looping to find the current index based on the value you wanted to shift. I created a map keyed on the 'value' that will return the next index into the chars[] array.  So given 'D' the map returns the index of 'E'.  There are probably better ways but this saved a significant amount of processing time.

```
...
int charIndex = 0;
foreach (char c in chars)
{
   if (c == chr)
   {
      shiftChars[index] = chars[charIndex + 1];
   }
   charIndex++;
}
...
```

Replaced with:

```
shiftChars[index] = chars[charsLookupNext[chr]];
```

The CPU Diagnostics in VC show 65% of time in Shift() and 30% in the checkBuffers().  I know checkBuffers() is quick so that bodes well for Shift().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace PwdCrackPerf
{
    class Program
    {
        private static UInt64 guesses = 0;       
        private static char[] currentGuessBuffer;
        private static readonly char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};

        private static readonly Dictionary<char,int> charsLookupNext = new Dictionary<char, int>() {{'a',1}, {'b',2}, {'c',3}, {'d',4}, {'e',5}, {'f',6}, {'g',7},
        { 'h',8}, {'i',9}, {'j',10}, {'k',11}, {'l',12}, {'m',13}, {'n',14}, {'o',15}, {'p',16}, {'q',17}, {'r',18}, {'s',19}, {'t',20}, {'w',21}, {'x',22}, {'y',23},
        { 'z',24}, {'A',25}, {'B',26}, {'C',27}, {'D',28}, {'E',29}, {'F',30}, {'G',31}, {'H',32}, {'I',33}, {'J',34}, {'K',35}, {'L',36}, {'M',37}, {'N',38}, {'O',39},
        { 'P',40}, {'Q',41}, {'R',42}, {'S',43}, {'T',44}, {'W',45}, {'X',46}, {'Y',47}, {'Z',48}, {'1',49}, {'2',50}, {'3',51}, {'4',52}, {'5',53}, {'6',54}, {'7',55},
        { '8',56}, {'9',57}, {'0',58}};

        private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateGuessCount));
           thread.Start();

           var passwordBuffer = args[0].ToCharArray();
           currentGuessBuffer = new char[passwordBuffer.Length];
           currentGuessBuffer[0] = chars[0];

           var tailIndex = 0;
           while ( !checkBuffers(passwordBuffer, currentGuessBuffer))
           {
               Shift(ref currentGuessBuffer, ref tailIndex);
               guesses++;
           }
           cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
           Console.WriteLine($"Password: {new string(currentGuessBuffer)}");
           Console.ReadKey();      
          return;
       }

       static bool checkBuffers(char[] charBuffer1, char[] charBuffer2)
       {
           var index = 0;
           while ((charBuffer1[index] == charBuffer2[index]) && ++index < charBuffer1.Length) ;
           return index == charBuffer1.Length;
       }       

       static void Shift(ref char[] shiftChars,ref int tailIndex)
       {            
           int index = 0;
           char chr = shiftChars[index];

           if (chr == chars[chars.Length-1])
           {
               while (chr == chars[chars.Length-1])
               {
                  shiftChars[index++] = chars[0];
                  if (index < shiftChars.Length)
                      chr = shiftChars[index];
                  else break;
               }
               if (index <= tailIndex)
                   shiftChars[index] = chars[charsLookupNext[chr]];                   
               else if(tailIndex+1<shiftChars.Length)
                   shiftChars[++tailIndex] = chars[0];                
            }
            else
                shiftChars[index] = chars[charsLookupNext[chr]];                                
        }

        static void UpdateGuessCount()
        {
            UInt64 lastGuessCount=0;
            while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
               //Just for ballpark
               Console.Clear();
               Console.WriteLine($"Current guesses: {guesses}");
               Console.WriteLine($"Current guesses per second: {guesses-lastGuessCount}");
               Console.WriteLine($"Current guess:{new string(currentGuessBuffer)}");
               lastGuessCount = guesses;
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
           }
       }
   }
}
```